# MySQL adapt JOIN according to the scenario

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have two tables with the following structures:

exp_hotel

```
hot_id | hot_webid | hot_name | hot_starrating | hot_brandbool | hot_latitude | hot_longitude
```

exp_result

```
res_id | res_idHotel | res_rank | res_price | res_userRating | res_oldPrice | res_posa | res_date | res_date | res_que_id
```

res_posa has sometimes either the value 'xxx' or the value 'yyy'.

If it has the value 'xxx', the SELECT should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM exp_hotel JOIN exp_result ON hot_id = res_idHotel
```

And if res_posa value is 'yyy' than the SELECT would be:

```
SELECT * FROM exp_hotel JOIN exp_result ON hot_webid = res_idHotel
```

Is there a way how to create a query wich would select everything with the correct JOIN structure directly from MySQL without going through some PHP arrays and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional join like below.

```
SELECT * FROM exp_hotel JOIN exp_result ON 
(res_posa = 'XXX' and  hot_id = res_idHotel)
OR
(res_posa = 'YYY' and hot_webid = res_idHotel);
```

Mock up fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74494).

Comment: You are welcome. You can close the question by accepting the answer if it works for you.